# webpack.config,js: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

The problem is that I get this very error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) when I use webpack-dev-server. But if I just build the project then I can run my index.html and get the expected result. My project structure is:

I have tried with above code but am getting 404 error failed to load resource
i think i have done something wrong, unable to get it